# Is a product of nonsquares in a finite group necessarily a square?

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a finite group. An element $a$ in $G$ is called a square if there exist x in G such that $x^2=a$. Is it true that if $a$ and $b$ are not square, then $ab$ is a square?

I have verified that above is true for all cyclic groups. What in general?

Comment: Abelian groups should work:
$a=x^2$, $b=y^2$, then $ab = xxyy=xyxy = (xy)^2$.

Comment: Martin, your proof is that "if a and b ARE  squares then ab is also".  The question asked was "if a and b are NOT squares, is ab a square?

Comment: Aw your right misread that part

Comment: Generally speaking, if you have tested a conjecture on all cyclic groups, try it next on a noncyclic group; cyclic groups are rather special, after all. To put it more broadly, if you have tested a conjecture on all BLAH groups, and if BLAH is a rather special class of groups, try the conjecture next on a non-BLAH group.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Consider the simplest noncyclic group, $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_2$. What is the square of each element $(a, b)$?

Comment: @ nice..got it.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found it helpful!